Netty, use channel executor to send message
I thought the cost per call to writeAndFlush was too high, so I did it like this.
I tried using flushQueue in channelReadCompleted, but addMessage was probably called from another thread. As a result, that message hung in the queue until there was a read event, and it might have hung in the queue indefinitely.
Does anyone have a better solution?
public class Sender {
    private final Session session;
    private final Queue<Message> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    public ScheduledFuture<?> future;

    public Sender(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        future = session.getCtx().executor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::flushMessages, 50, 50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    public void addMessage(Message message) {
        messages.add(message);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        future.cancel(false);
    }

    public void flushMessages() {
        Message message = messages.poll();
        if (message != null) {
            ByteBuf buffer = PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT.buffer();
            do {
                buffer.writeBytes(message.getBuffer());
                message.release();

                message = messages.poll();
            } while (message != null);

            session.getCtx().writeAndFlush(buffer);
        }
    }
}

EDIT:
I gave up using a message queue. Instead, I just write to the channel and call flush after each interval. However, I still hope there is a better way.
futureFlushEvent = ctx.channel().eventLoop().scheduleAtFixedRate(ctx::flush, 100, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


